# Domain of hash function

Tags: notation, cryptography, hash-function

I am reading Buchmann's Introduction to Cryptography, 2nd ed.
On page 267,

> $G$ is a finite cyclic group of prime order $q$. $a\in\mathbb{Z}_{q}=\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$. $h:\{0,1\}^{*}\to G$ is a hash function. $m\in G$. The signer computes $s=h(m)^{a}$.

I am not sure what $h(m)$ means. I know that the set $\{0,1\}^{*}$ contains all words in $0,1$. For example, $0101$ is in this set. But $m$ is in $G$. How do I compute $h(m)$? Thank you.

Comment: It is a hash function that the output is just $G$.

Comment: @kelalaka The part I don't understand is the input. $m$ is in $G$, and $m$ is not in the domain of $h$. So how does the function work in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The star in $h:\{0,1\}^{*}\to G$ is the [Kleene star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star) and it simply means **zero or more repetition**. You may consider the input space as the string of 0 and 1 of arbitrary but finite size.

At first sight, you may say that $m$ need not be in the domain of $h$. If we look a little deeper, we see that we can encode any set, group, field, etc. with $\{0,1\}^{*}$, we already do this with computers, right!.

Let say the size of the group is $\ell$ then you only need bit strings of at most size $\lfloor \log_2 (  \ell )\rfloor +1\;$ to encode them. You only need an order on the group even that it need not be meaningful. The reverse process, decoding, exists since encoding is 1-1.

Now once you encoded the $h$ work with any object. This encoding definition is not part of the hash functions.

Comment: So if $G=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}=\{0,1,2,3\}$, we can encode $0$ to be $0$, $1$ to be $1$, $2$ to be $10$, and $3$ to be $11$. Then $h(2)=h(10)$, right? Thanks!

Comment: That's it. With groups formed integers it is easy, for others, it might little harder but not impossible.

Comment: [This might enlighten you more](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/87012/how-to-use-these-hash-functions-in-python/87013#87013).

Comment: Also, note that we put a limit for the message sizes for [cryptographic hash functions](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/87463/18298)  though this is not necessary for SHA3 or Blake2, we still use the size and fix an upper bound. In recent hash functions the upper bound can't be reached.